# Accessing dynamic variable from within data array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have got a bit stuck dynamically setting a value within an Object.  So I am loading some data inside my created hook

```
created() {
    let vm = this;
    axios.all([
        axios.get('/api/report/someUrl'),
        axios.get('/api/report/someUrl')
    ]).then(axios.spread(function (response1, response2) {
        vm.dynamicValue = response2.data['someKey'].toString();
    }))
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

So the above is setting a variable in my data array

```
data() {
    return {
        dynamicValue: '',
        histogramOptions: {
            histogram: {
                bucketSize: this.dynamicValue
            },
        },
    }
}
```

The issue is, I need to use `dynamicValue` within the histogram options.  The way I have it currently, I am getting an undefined value.  Normally I would set a variable to `this`, but I cant seem to do that within the data array.

So how would I pass `dynamicValue` within the histogram options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`histogramOptions` should be a computed property, considering `dynamicValue`. Like:

```
computed: {
  histogramOptions() {
    histogram: {
      bucketSize: this.dynamicValue,
    },
  },
},
```

So you will be able to access `this.histogramOptions`, which is reactive to `this.dynamicValue`.